# Operation not supported. Unknown error: 0x80070057 - when tryng to run Roslyn source generator

Tags: visual-studio, roslyn

I have created a Roslyn source code generator.

1. Right-click project in Solution Explorer
2. Edit project
3. Inside `<PropertyGroup>` add `<IsRoslynComponent>true</IsRoslynComponent>`
4. Right-click project in Solution Explorer
5. Properties
6. Debug settings
7. Create new profile
8. Set type to "Roslyn Component"
9. Select a project that consumes the source generator
10. Run

```
---------------------------
Microsoft Visual Studio
---------------------------
Unable to start debugging.

Operation not supported. Unknown error: 0x80070057.
---------------------------
OK
---------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I had since right-clicked the consuming project and chosen "Unload project", which causes the above error upon running the project.

To fix it

1. Right-click project in Solution Explorer
2. Properties
3. Debug settings
4. Click the profile you made for your Roslyn debugging
5. In the dropdown, select the consuming project